# Limit OAuth 2.0 client IDs for a google api project

Tags: android, google-api, google-developers-console

I have created 36 OAuth client id for my project. But now when I create new OAuth client id it gives me an error saying

> This project has reached its maximum number of OAuth clients. To
>   create another, first remove an existing one.

[image]

Whereas I have another project in which I have created 100 client Id's.

Is there any limit of OAuth client id according to the project or there might be any other issue with my project?

Answer (score 3):

We do have a hard limit of OAuth Client IDs per project, but there are several factors that limits the number of OAUTH clients. For this reason, we do not document a specific number, as any number we provide would seem inaccurate depending on each situation.

We're working to help increase it. More details can be found in the following [Feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/69347593)

Answer (score 2):

There is a limit of 36 OAuth Client ids and, but you can´t add more slots for more credentials, but you can write directly to Google about your requirements, if your project requires more credentials and it is approved by Google the can help you to  increase the number of slots.

[image]

Comment: Hi Jorgesys, may I know where/how you send the request to Google? I've talked to them and they were pretty firm on the 36 limits. Thank you!