# Adding oauth clientId fail with maximum limit of the resource

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-sso

While i'm trying to create new `OAuth client ID` (APIs & Services -> Credentials -> + Create credentials -> OAuth client Id) for Android appplication (with package name and SHA-1 of release certyficate) i'm getting `Creaed failed` with message `The request failed because the maximum limit of the resource would be exceeded.`. I have more than 200 android apps (white label) but with shared account for Google OAuth. How can i increase limit for OAuth clients for my application? Unfrotunatelly i cannot find any usefull information in Google Cloud Platform documenation and there in Stack Overflow.[image]

Comment: I found nothing relevant. Ask the support or your Google Customer Engineer/Sales

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limit OAuth 2.0 client IDs for a google api project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49531154/limit-oauth-2-0-client-ids-for-a-google-api-project)